# "Switch windows of an application" shortcut has an associated "Switch to previous window of an application" shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

The application switcher is no longer switching backwards with Shift+Alt+Tab. It does switch backwards with Shift+Super+Tab. I am using the alternative Alt-Tab extension. I tried disabling it but nothing changed.

When trying to set the shortcut in the Keyboard Shortcuts dialog box to Alt+TAB, I get the following message:

> The "Switch windows of an application" shortcut has an associated
>   "Switch to previous window of an application" shortcut. Do you want to
>   automatically set it to "Shift+Alt+TAB"?

dconf editor under `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings` has two entries:

```
switch-applications = ['<Super>Tab', '<Alt>Tab']  
switch-applications-backward = ['<Shift><Super>Tab', '<Shift><Alt>Tab']
```

How do I restore the original behaviour?

Comment: I tried that but there was no change. Furthermore, switch-applications may not be the same as switch-windows. There's no such entry in dconf-editor though.

Comment: I checked again dconf-editor and now there are entries for switch-windows and switch-windows-backward and they're set to Alt+Tab and Shift+Alt+Tab.

Comment: Hi, it turns out this is due to a non-gnome settings for xkb overriding it. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396900/why-does-not-the-gnome-keyboard-settings-override-clear-the-xkb-settings

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found that (as stated in the question's comments) there are the following four entries related to this:

- **switch-applications**: Alt+Tab, Super+Tab
- **switch-applications-backward**: Alt+Shift+Tab, Super+Shift+Tab
- **switch-windows**: Alt+Tab
- **switch-windows-backward**: Alt+Shift+Tab

After removing the values from the switch-windows entries, Alt+Tab and Alt+Shift+Tab were working fine again.

Not sure what set them in the first place tough.

Comment: "Not sure what set them in the first place" - According to dconf, it's default for both Super and Tab to switch by application, not window, despite that most would expect Tab to switch by window. I think that's just GNOME enforcing a paradigm that disagrees not only with users' intuition but also, hilariously, their own defaults _elsewhere_ - i.e. in Keyboard. I changed them to what IMO they should be - and what Keyboard implies misleadingly they are: `switch_applications*` with Super, and `switch-windows*` with Tab. Now keys actually do what Keyboard says they will. Incredible! Thanks, GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably caused by a setting for XKB, which overrides the other Gnome keyboard settings. You can check out the [background story here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1396900/why-does-not-the-gnome-keyboard-settings-override-clear-the-xkb-settings), but essentially clearing the settings fixes this:

See the value messing it up:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['grp:alt_shift_toggle', 'grp_led:scroll']
```

Clear it to regain Alt-Shift for other uses:

```
$ gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options

$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
@as []
```